# Using $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); with Symfony 3.3 Command

Tags: mysql, symfony

I need to connect to a MySQL database from inside a Symfony Command. In a Controller, it is easy to do with:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

Can I do the same with a Command? If so, how?

The error message I get when I try to run the above inside a Command says this:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "AppBundle\Command\{NameOfMyComand}"
```

Comment: Maybe you should read in the docs how the dependency injection works in Symfony, what it is in general then how to apply it to the commands.

Comment: Can you share more details? If that method is not defined, it's obvious that you cannot call it

Comment: Since it is 3.3 you might try using $this->container->getDoctrine()->getManager().  However, the answer below is the 'correct approach' for later versions of Symfony.  The answer below may or may not work for you depending on exactly how you app is configured.  Back in S2.x commands were not defined as services by default.  Hence the container was automatically injected.  Somewhere in the S3.x cycle this changed.  So again it will depend on your specific app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Works with Symfony v. 4 and 5** *(I have not tested with v. 3)*

In a Command, or any Service, you have to inject the dependencies you need in the `__construct` method like so :

```
namespace App\Command;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
...

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em = $em;

        // In a Command, you *must* call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected static $defaultName = 'my:command';

    protected function configure()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        ...
        
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

More infos : https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html

Comment: Good answer but always pay attention to the version involved.  Back in Symfony 2 and partly into S3, commands were not routinely defined as services.  Depending on when the app in question was first started, your answer may or may not be applicable.  Commands used to extend ContainerAwareCommand which in turn provided access to the container via a property.